# How to plot a plane with three variables in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

If have a function x+y+2z=5, how can I plot it with gnuplot? Using splot gives error that z isn't defined. How do I define it?

Answer (score 2):

`splot` works with an explicit definition of `z=f(x,y)`, thus, in your case:

```
splot (5-x-y)/2
```